# How to create a React component using the dot notation and share state with its derivative components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a hypothetical component called `NavigationBar` and I would like to create a mobile and desktop version of this by creating another component using the dot notation.

```js
class NavigationBar extends React.PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      // values
    }

  }
  render() {
    return (
      // jsx
    )

  }

  static MobileView = () => {
    console.log(this.state) // undefined
  }

  static DesktopView = () => {
    console.log(this.state) // undefined
  }
}
```

The problem is when I tried this, the state of `NavigationBar` is not accessible to the components `NavigationBar.MobileView` and `NavigationBar.DesktopView`. How do I construct derivative components and share the state of the primary component to its derivative components?

Essentially, I wanted to know if it is possible to create `NavigationBar` and have `NavigationBar.MobileView` and `NavigationBar.DesktopView` share the state of `NavigationBar` without the need for Redux or React Context and the like.

My motivation for doing this is so that I can simply import `NavigationBar` and have access to multiple components to do `NavigationBar.MobileView` etc. instead of having to do multiple imports for every component I create even though they are related.

Comment: Those two methods are static. You cannot use state inside them since state is assigned to object created with `NavigationBar` class.

Comment: I hope I'm understanding this right. So the reason is that static methods cannot access the variables declared in the primary object right? That's why I cannot access the state of `NavigationBar` inside of `NavigationBar.MobileView` and `NavigationBar.DesktopView`. What if I made use of a function component and initialized a state using `useState` and created derivative components using the dot notation again, would that work? I tried doing it but I don't know exactly how to pass or access the state this way.

Comment: I will place explanation in answer since it will be longer and I do not have enough characters here.

Answer (score 0):

**Here Are Few ways To Share State In React (Accodring to React Team)**

1. Use Props To share State to Child Component e.g `<Child1 props={...state}`
2. Using State Management Library like - https://redux.js.org/introduction/getting-
   started
3. using Context - https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html
   React Wont Let You use Other way and it create State Inside the Constructor As Far As I Know Please Read React Documentation It is free.

Comment: I have already implemented this using redux (also tried with React context) and its working as I wanted it to but I was just wondering if it is possible to access state of a parent component inside a component created using the dot notation. I have not been successful so far with it and there seems to be no documentation for that.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting undefined because it really is undefined.

Static methods/functions/parameters/variables are accessed/stored globally inside memory, not inside object.

If I have something like this:

```
class MyClass {

    constructor(id) {
        this.ID = id; // this is bound to object created by this class
    }

    // This is bound to object created by this class
    PrintID() {

        // "this" referes to object from which this function is called

        return this.ID;
    }

    // This is not bound to object, you do not need object to call this
    static PrintIDButStatic() {

        // "this" referes to object from which this function is called
        // since static functions are not bound to any object but program
        // itself, it has no data

        return this.ID;
    }
}
```

As we can see in class up, we have constructor with some parameter `ID`, one "normal" function and one `static` function.

I will call those functions now with explanations:

```
var a = MyClass.ID; // Will return undefined since MyClass do not have any static property named ID

MyClass.PrintID(); // Will not call any function since MyClass do not have any static method named PrintID()

MyClass.PrintIDButStatic(); // Will call function since it is static

var objectCreatedUsingMyClass = new MyClass(); // Creating object using myclass
var a = objectCreatedUsingMyClass.ID; // Will return value
objectCreatedUsingMyClass.PrintID(); // Will call function
objectCreatedUsingMyClass.PrintIDButStatic(); // Will not call function since it is static
```

Now as you can see from this, your problem was that you were calling static function and from within it using `this.property` but since static functions are not bound to anything but program itself, then `this` is `null` and you get undefined.

I do not see any more of your code so do not know logic of your component up there, but to solve this you should make those functions not static (remove that keyword) and then they will be bound to object, so they will have data of that object.

If you post more code so I can see logic of component, I will edit this answer to add solution in more details.

EDIT: Since you draw navigation bar based on screen size we will do it like this:

```
class NavigationBar extends React.PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        currentScreenSize: window.innerWidth
    }
    // We listen to screen resize from within component
    window.addEventListener('resize', this.UpdateDimensions);

    // So we can use this inside functions
    RenderBasedOnScreenSize = RenderBasedOnScreenSize.bind(this)
    MobileView = MobileView.bind(this)
    DesktopView = DesktopView.bind(this)
    UpdateDimensions = UpdateDimensions.bind(this)
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <div className="navigation-bar">
            <this.RenderBasedOnScreenSize />
        </div>
    )
  }

  UpdateDimensions() {
    // setState will fire render() function again
    this.setState({
      currentScreenSize: window.innerWidth
    })
  }

  RenderBasedOnScreenSize() {
     if(this.state.currentScreenSize < 960) {
         return MobileView();
     }
     return DesktopView();
  }

  MobileView() {
    return (<div>Hi Mobile</div>)
  }

  DesktopView() {
    return (<div>Hi Desktop</div>)
  }
}
```

Comment: How do you determine if you need to return mobile or desktop view?

Comment: Currently I am using a resize event to detect the window size. There's not much in the NavigationBar class right now. Just an empty state and I am returning a div with a text of  "This is navigation bar" in the `NavigationBar`. I have tried using redux to detach the state from the components and make it "more accessible" (it's working as expected) but I just wanted to know if the same effect could be achieved with just a React state.

Comment: Okay. Edit coming now I know it depends on size.

Comment: I could really simply create different components for mobile and desktop view and just display one or the other inside the `App` but I just wanted to know if I could make it so that I could just import `NavigationBar` and do `width < 768 ? <NavigationBar.MobileView /> : <NavigationBar.MobileView />` instead of importing two separate components.

Comment: @Euphmin I did edit it. I wrote it all here (not in editor) so error may appear.